# Re-assining 'K' in var

Tags: c#

I have written a piece of code as following:

```
var i=5;
i='K';
```

The code is being compiled without an error. As far as my concept is concerned, I cannot re-assign a value in var. Since I have assigned integer 5 to i. the type of i is int. Then why it is allowing to assign a char 'K' in i?

Comment: `int i = 'K';` is perfectly legal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# char to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/c-sharp-char-to-int)

Answer (score 8):

Because a `char` can be implicitly cast to an `int`. The type of the variable `i` would still be `int` – you can test this using `i.GetType()` – and its value would be the codepoint of the character `'K'` (namely, `75`).

In other words, your code is equivalent to writing:

```
int i = 'K';
```

“As far as my concept is concerned, I cannot re-assign a value in var.” – That is not correct. You cannot change the *type* of an implicitly-typed variable (just like you cannot change the declared type of any other variable), but you are allowed to re-assign it another value of the same type (or one that may be cast as so).

Answer (score 0):

`i` is implicitly typed as an integer during your first assignment.  Then you are attempting to assign a char value to an integer.