# Convert a string containing a number to an int

Tags: c#, char, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# char to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/c-sharp-char-to-int)

I have come across many solutions to this but I can't get it right by trying any of them. 
How can I convert string values like "230", "73400" or bigger to int values in c#? Will I have to use a library? Is there a way to do it natively to c#?
Lets assume:

> `string c = "270"; int i;`

How can I get i to be 270 as well?

Comment: Are you asking about converting a string containing the characters '2', '7' and '0' to an int?

Comment: Ok, I realised I should have mentioned an array of characters or a string. I was having difficulty with some parsing methods, but methods like sscanf and atoi worked great for me! thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible
`char c = '270';`

but you can have a string `string c ="270";` and the best way would be to go by using `int.TryParse(c, out intval)` variant which would return true if you have a parsable int value contained in the string. Also in the value examples you mentioned i think you would need a `long`.

Comment: +1 for realizing the "real problem" :)

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
int i = (int) c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = Char.GetNumericValue('270');

//or 

int i= Convert.ToInt32(c);
```

try this,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string containing "270" you can use a few different methods:

```
var s = "270";

var i1 = Convert.ToInt32(s);
var i2 = int.Parse(s);

// This is probably safest as it allows you to handle errors yourself without catching exceptions.
int i3;
if(! int.TryParse(s, out i3)) {
  // Panic!
}
```