# Convert numeric string character to int32

Tags: c#

If I have a string of digits and `int` variables `a, b, c` and I want to assign the first digit to `int a`, the second to `int b` and so on, how do I do that?  This snippet illustrates my problem:

```
var str = "123";
int a = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
Console.WriteLine(str[0] + " " + a );
```

Output:

```
1 49
```

What do I do (besides subtract 48 from every attempted conversion)?

**EDIT**

Today I learned that `str[0]` produces a `Char`, not a `string`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `str` instead of index at 0?

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Or maybe you don't understand.  I want `int a == 1`, `int b == 2`, `int c == 3`.

Comment: Side note: "string" generally refer to `string` type in C# questions and in your case you are talking about "characters of a string" which are in C# represented by `char` type. Using proper words could either helped you to find solution (i.e. duplicate with more C#/.Net approach than C-style solution you've accepted) or at least help others in answering.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know that `str[0]` was a `char`. Obviously if I'd known that, I wouldn't have asked the question. I did try to search before asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a = str[0] - '0';
int b = str[1] - '0';
int c = str[2] - '0';
```

etc...

This works because `str[0]` is a `char`, and so is `'0'`, and subtracting chars gives you an `int` in C#.

<sub>P.S. Well, strictly speaking, it's not that subtracting `char`s gives you an `int`. Subtraction is not defined for `char`, but chars are implicitly convertible to `int`, so that's what happens: two implicit conversions into `int`, and those can obviously be subtracted from each other to give another `int`.</sub>

Comment: +1 for C-style solution. For .Net one check [char to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/c-sharp-char-to-int). Strictly speaking this is exactly "besides subtract 48 from every attempted conversion" from the question...

Comment: Well... I consider a cast of `char` to `int` to be C#-style, and I consider *parsing* a *single-character* number neither a good idea nor more idiomatic in C#.

Comment: At the end of the day, in my opinion, this is more elegant than `int a = Char.GetNumericValue(str[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Convert.ToInt32(char)` overload. Try with `ToString`:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(str[0].ToString());
```

Another way using Math (which I'm not really good at)

```
string x = "123";
int number = int.Parse(x);
int first = number / 100;
int second = (number % 100) / 10;
int third = number % 10;
```

Comment: OK.  Seems clunky.  Is there no more elegant way?  Thanks

Comment: A third way `int b = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(1,1));`

Answer (score 0):

To build on Selman22's answer:

```
var str = "123";
int digit = GetDigit(str, 1);
Response.Write(digit.ToString()); // Prints '1'

int GetDigit(String s, Int32 digitPos)
{
  var actualDigitPos = (s.Length - digitPos) + 1;
  var number = Int32.Parse(s);

  return (number % (Int32)Math.Pow(10, actualDigitPos)) / (Int32)Math.Pow(10, actualDigitPos - 1);
}
```

Keep in mind, you should add some sort of validation on string length and digitPos, as well as a valid String, etc.