# Is there a way to convert Char into Int without using numbers?

Tags: c#, char, int

The title says everything. I'm trying to convert char into int in visual studio.

I have already tried this:

```
int a;
a = (int)x;
System.Console.WriteLine(a);
```

but it's not giving me anything besides this(from trying to understand the code):
114117105

Comment: What is `x`? Can you provide a proper [mcve]?

Comment: "The title says everything" Not really, in particular not what `x` actually is when executing the code.

Comment: char test = '1';
int result = test - '0';

Comment: `char x = "kajdgysf"` is **NOT** a char

Comment: @RuiPedro you can [edit] your question - please do so. `char x = "kajdgysf"` isn't valid C# and does not compile.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in your question, not comments). Be sure to show inputs **and the expected output for those inputs**.

Comment: [char (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char)

Comment: Even if your input **were** a signle character - which it apprently is not - how would you expect `"kajdgysf"` to be converted to a number? Your question is still completely unclear.

Comment: hi you can follow below thread for your solution :- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

This will just work:

```
//a char is a 16-bit numerical value
//usually used for the representation of characters
//here I assign 'a' to it; keep in mind; 'a' has also a numeric representation
//i.e.: 97
char x = 'a';

int a;

//the `int a` is an integer and, through a cast, receives the numeric value
//besides the bit-width (debatable) the data contents are the same.
//If we assign it to an `int` only the "purpose" c.q. representation will change
a = (int)x;

//since we put in an `int` a number will be shown (because of it's purpose)
//if we put in x, then `a` will be shown.
System.Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Output

```
97
```

As you have understand by now; a `string`, is an `array` of `char`s.
Therefore a string is hard to represent by a single number, because it is 2 dimensional.

It would be the same as saying, convert: `0,4,43434,878728,3477,3.14159265` to a single number.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qSYUdP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char

On why the output for `a` is `97`; you can look it up in the character table, e.g.: [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Please note that the actual character that is outputted is determined by the chosen font/character table. For most fonts the ASCII is implemented, but it's not guaranteed. So, `97` will not always produce `a`.

Comment: I don't know why that happens, but Thank you.

Comment: I mean the letter. why did it give the result 97?

Comment: @RuiPedro because binary number 97 represents ascii character 'a'. Look it up here: http://www.asciitable.com/