# How to better cast a char to int keeping the number value and not the ASCII value?

Tags: c#

I have just wrote a code(c#) for my sample exam in C# basics study.

Еven though I was able to write it correctly and receive all points, I am not quite satisfied with the way I have used to cast the char ASCII value to the desired int value.
I am asking for a better way to express the following code:

using System;

```
namespace MultiplyTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Input:
            string inputNumber = Console.ReadLine();

            //Logic:

            int firstNumber = 0;
            int secondNumber = 0;
            int thirdNumber = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < inputNumber.Length; i++)
            {
                firstNumber = inputNumber[0] - 48;
                secondNumber = inputNumber[1] - 48;
                thirdNumber = inputNumber[2] - 48;
            }

            for (int p = 1; p <= thirdNumber; p++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= secondNumber; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= firstNumber; k++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{p} * {j} * {k} = {p * j * k};");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The input is an integer three-digit number in the range [111… 999].
I have used string instead of int, to quicker read and store all char values.
The issue here is that when I have the char let's say '3' I need to use the int value of '3' and not the ASCII Dec value of 51.
As I had a limited time to write this code I succeeded to resolve it by subtracting 48 as you can see in the code provided.
What is the correct/more advanced way to do this exercise ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use [`Char.GetNumericValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful, I tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Substracting `foo`'s ASCII value from `0`'s ASCII value will give you number.

```
char foo = '2';
int bar = foo - '0';
```

Or you can just simply convert char to string and then convert to int:

```
int bar = int.Parse(foo.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this was the way I initially have used, as '0' has ASCII value of 48. The method I searched for was Char.GetNumericValue(inputNumber[0])

Comment: As Zohar already commented, the acceped answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp using [Char.GetNumericValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8) is better as it also correctly converts digit characters outside the range '0'...'9' (like e.g. digits in other scripts, super/subscript digits etc.).

Comment: Yes it is but i wanted to show another solutions as well.