# Getting different values from convert char to integer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, char, type-conversion, int

when I display the 'i' variable, which would be a char value

```
{
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var max = 0;
      var lista = new char[] {
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4'
      };
      foreach(char i in lista) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        /* var hola =  Convert.ToInt32(i);
          Console.WriteLine(hola);*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this:

```
> 1 2 3 4
```

However, when converting 'i' into an int

```
var max = 0;
var lista = new char[] {
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4'
};
foreach(char i in lista) {
  var hola = Convert.ToInt32(i);
  Console.WriteLine(hola);
}
```

I get this:

> 49 50 51 52

Any idea what could be the problem? I'd like to obtain the same values, so I can evaluate them as integers and obtain the biggest of them, but I can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert char to int in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239103/convert-char-to-int-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert a `char` to an `int`, you get the ASCII value of that character. The neat thing with these values is that they are sequential, so if you subtract the value of `'0'` (the 0 **character**), you can convert a character representing a digit to that digit:

```
var hola =  i - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the literal character and not the ascii number of the character, use the `ToString()` method

```
var hola =  Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteLine method internally converts the parameters string. Thus you can have the value you want. ToInt method return the ASCII value of that char. You have to convert your i value to string `i.ToString()` or you can simply substract 48 from the converted value.