How to get specific digit in barcode as string
I'm trying to get every odd number in my barcode. For example my barcode is 100101000316 and im trying to get 1 0 0 0 0 1. How can i get the specific digit in my barcode? This is my code
private string checkDigit(string barcode)
{
    int OddNum = 0;
    int OddNumSum;
    for (var num = 0; barcode.Length > num; num += 2 )
    {
        OddNum = OddNum + barcode[num];
    }
}

but the value im getting in my breakpoint in visual studio is 49'1', 48, '0', 47 '0', 46 '0', 45 '0', 44 '1' and the value that im getting is the 49, 48 ...
What i need is inside the single quote.

Since when is 0 an odd number?

Are you sure you want to get the result as an int, and not a string?

When posting, please use the preview to check that the formatting is how you intend - see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details on formatting.

@Sweeper I mean the every odd place value in my barcode.

@canton7 as an int. Im adding every digit i get from that barcode and after that loop im gonna multiple that number to 3

@devChing You're getting each char, which all have an underlying integer value. The character 1 has the ASCII value 49. You would need to convert the character to an integer. See the ASCII table here: https://www.asciitable.com/

I think this answer is relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/239107/8551479

So your desired result is actually 2 ?

@PontusMagnusson That helped me a lot. Thank you very much

The [] operator of a string returns a char. You're getting the numeric (ASCII) value of that digit. Since the digits are consecutive ASCII characters, the easiest thing to do is subtract the charater '0', and thus get the offset from it, which would be the digit you're looking for.
Then, it's just a matter of summing them up:
private static int checkDigit(string barcode)
{

    int OddNumSum = 0;
    for (var num = 0; barcode.Length > num; num += 2 )
    {
        OddNumSum += barcode[num] - '0';
    }
    return OddNumSum;
}


Yes exaclty what im looking for. Thank you very much!
